# how to fix errors in multiple .json files in one step?

Tags: r, json

I am trying to load a local json file in R. I am using a package called Sofia that includes the json library. I also tried other packages like `rjson` and the `RJSONIO` packages but I get the same error

> error in ProcessFiles(File=File), unexpected character E.

This is example code when I use the a local package Sofia:

```
data<-ProcessFiles(file="data1.json",method="Sofia.method")
```

When I apply the same package to some old .json files it works normally without error. I tried to change the encoding of the file to UTF-8 but the error persists. The file encoding is ANSI Can anybody help with this?
I ran the online linter and I seemed to discover the error however I want to fix these syntax errors in multple json files in one step, does anybody know how?

Comment: Can you include a short example of a json file that produces this error in your question? What is causing the syntax error?

Comment: Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code (including listing non-base R packages), sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(x=...,y=...)`), and expected output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.